# Problem of Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-value

I try to solve this equation numerically :

```
eq= z''[t] + (2691+ D[Log[Abs[z'[t]^2]],t]) (z'[t]^2 + Abs[z'[t]]^2 ) == 0;
```

By `NDSolveValue` with arbitrary initial conditions:

```
NDSolveValue[{eq, z[0]==0.1, z'[0]==1}, z, {t,0,25}]
```

But this gives an error:

`Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.`

**Declaration:**

The error goes when I remove the `Abs` function, I.e., writing `z'[t]^2` instead of `Abs[z'[t]]^2` .

However the function `z[t]` is complex and I want to keep solving in case of `Abs[z'[t]]^2`. Any idea how to write this in a better syntax so that Mathematica can find numerical values?

Thanks

Comment: `However the function z[t]  is complex` but this is the function you are solving for. How do you know it is complex before solving for it? It is better to just solve for `z[t]` and after finding the solution you could look at its abs, real part or imaginary part and so on.

Comment: I know the function is complex because I'm studing,  so in my analytic calculations there are `z[t]` and $z^*[t]$ . But I wanna to avoid using `Conjugate[z[t]]` in `NDSolve` so I'm using `Abs` instead.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use `RealAbs` :

```
eq = z''[t] + (2691 + D[Log[RealAbs[z'[t]^2]], t]) (z'[t]^2 + RealAbs[z'[t]]^2) == 0;
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, z[0] == 0.1, z'[0] == 1}, z, {t, 0, 25}];
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0., 25.}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rmw , but `RealAbs`  is for real numbers, so the result is the same as if I used `z'[t] ^2` . I just think numeric solving for complex numbers in Mathemtica is not trivial